# Magento $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) not showing

Tags: magento, block, product

I'm not entirely sure why this is not working, and I've been stuck on it for hours.

I have a file called **banners.phtml**, which is created using the following layout update:

```
<block type="catalog/product" name="banners" template="page/html/banners.phtml">
<!-- there are further blocks in here, but aren't important --->
</block>
```

The type is **catalog/product**, and on the page I have a loop which feeds an SKU to each product Model load:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', get_field('product_sku')); ?>
```

Then when I use:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Nothing shows - it doesn't break the site, but nothing shows. I've seen it mentioned that the product block type needs to be loaded - but I thought that's what **catalog/product** was doing... Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Show your layout file. To which block you are trying to add banners?

Comment: it's within <reference name="root">

Comment: What is `get_field('product_sku')` here? There is no such function in magento.

Comment: That's a wordpress plugin function - this part is working fine so ignore it.

Comment: Is that missing hyphen after `$this` in `echo $this>getPriceHtml($_product, true)` a typo, or a 1:1 copy of your code?

Comment: @Jurgen - yes you're right, this is a typo - but is not the reason why it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised the reason was because my collection was full of grouped products only. Therefore I added

```
->addMinimalPrice()
```

to the collection query and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the list.phtml file
2. Remove the code " getPriceHtml() ?>".
3. Add the following code to get the simple price for the product:- 

   "echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getPrice(), 'price')"

   Or

   To get the special price of the product use the following code:-

   " echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSpecialPrice(), 'price') "

   It surely works man. :)